# Matching two similar dates with different times

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, pandas

I have two dates in pandas dataframes (df1.a_date & df2.another_date) read from CSV files. They match at the date level (YYYY-MM-DD) but not at the time (HH:MM:SS). Both are read in as dtype: object.

I need to merge the two dataframes on the dates, but since they aren't exact, i probably need to convert them first. Any ideas?

edit:

I've tried using diatomite.date to construct a new date from the pandas.datetime, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
datetime.date(df.a_date.year, df.a_date.month, df.a_date.day)
```

pandas datetime objects don't have year, month, day accessors, though.

Comment: You convert the datetime column to just the date. Save it in a different column and `merge` on those columns.

Comment: that's basically what i've been trying to figure out, but i can't seem to nail down the exact code. Can you (or someone else) give an example?

Comment: Please start by putting out what you have tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normalize a date column/DatetimeIndex index:

*Note: At the moment normalize isn't exported to the dt accessor so we need to wrap with DatetimeIndex.*

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2015-01-01 05:00', periods=3), columns=['datetime'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
             datetime
0 2015-01-01 05:00:00
1 2015-01-02 05:00:00
2 2015-01-03 05:00:00

In [13]: df["date"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df["datetime"]).normalize()

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
             datetime       date
0 2015-01-01 05:00:00 2015-01-01
1 2015-01-02 05:00:00 2015-01-02
2 2015-01-03 05:00:00 2015-01-03
```

*This works if it's a DatetimeIndex too, use `df.index` rather than `df[col_name]`.*

Answer (score 0):

Format the datetime to only include YYYY-MM-DD:

assuming df is your dataframe:

```
'{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume, dft is your dataframe and 'index' column contains datetime:

```
In [1804]: dft.head()
Out[1804]: 
                index         A
0 2013-01-01 00:00:00  1.193366
1 2013-01-01 00:01:00  1.013425
2 2013-01-01 00:02:00  1.281902
3 2013-01-01 00:03:00 -0.043788
4 2013-01-01 00:04:00 -1.610164
```

You could convert the column to contain just the date and save it in a different column, if you want. And operate on that:

```
In [1805]: dft['index'].apply(lambda v:v.date()).head()
Out[1805]: 
0    2013-01-01
1    2013-01-01
2    2013-01-01
3    2013-01-01
4    2013-01-01
Name: index, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. Now i just need to deal with missing values.

Comment: @NicholasTulach This is going to be much slower than using either dt.date or dt.normalize (normalize being the fastest).